# Flink Streaming File Sink Producing And Uploading Different Versions Of The Same Part File

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm experienceing some odd behaviour when writing ORC files to S3 using flinks Streaming File Sink.

```
    StreamingFileSink<ArmadaRow> orderBookSink = StreamingFileSink
            .forBulkFormat(new Path(PARAMETER_TOOL_CONFIG.get("order.book.sink")),
                    new OrcBulkWriterFactory<>(new OrderBookRowVectorizer(_SCHEMA), writerProperties, new Configuration()))
            .withBucketAssigner(new OrderBookBucketingAssigner())
            .withRollingPolicy(OnCheckpointRollingPolicy.build())
            .build();
```

I noticed when running queries during ingest of the data, that my row counts were being decremented as the job progressed. I've had a look at S3 and I can seem multiple versions of the same part file. The example below shows part file 15-7 has two versions. The first file is 20.7mb and the last file that's committed is smaller at 5.1mb. In most cases the current file is normally larger but in my instance there are a few examples in the screenshot below where this is not the case.

[image: Smaller Version Of File Is Being Set As Current Version In S3]

I noticed from the logs on the TaskManager that Flink committed both these files at pretty much the same time. I'm not sure if this is known issue with Flinks streaming file sink or potentially some misconfiguration on my part. I'm using Flink 1.11 by the way.

```
2022-02-28T20:44:03.224+0000 INFO  APP=${sys:AppID} COMP=${sys:CompID} APPNAME=${sys:AppName} S3Committer:64 - Committing staging/marketdata/t_stg_globex_order_book_test2/cyc_dt=2021-11-15/inst_exch_mrkt_id=XNYM/inst_ast_sub_clas=Energy/part-15-7 with MPU ID 
2022-02-28T20:44:03.526+0000 INFO  APP=${sys:AppID} COMP=${sys:CompID} APPNAME=${sys:AppName} S3Committer:64 - Committing staging/marketdata/t_stg_globex_order_book_test2/cyc_dt=2021-11-15/inst_exch_mrkt_id=XNYM/inst_ast_sub_clas=Energy/part-15-7 with MPU ID
```

Edit

I've also tested this with version 1.13 and the same problem occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading To Flink 1.13 and using the new FileSink API resolved this error

https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.13/docs/connectors/datastream/file_sink/#bulk-encoded-formats